# Не получается подключить внешний модуль в Django, Python

Tags: python, django

У меня простой учебный проект на Django. Я отдельные вспомогательные функции вынесла в отдельный файл quotes.py и хочу его подключить в views.py и там его использовать. Файл находится в том же каталоге что и views.py.
import quotes
Пробовала просто файлом, пробовала пакетом, результат один ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: попробуйте `from . import quotes`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Работает. Пол дня бьюсь, а тут только спросила.

Comment: Дело в том, что вы импортируете модули внутри одного пакета. Соответственно поиск начинается от самого пакета, поэтому вначале ставится точка, то есть искать модуль `quotes` внутри того же пакета, откуда происходит импорт

Comment: relative import

Comment: Спасибо. Поняла.